# How to do data analytics on-chain

Tags: database, data

as I understand it, data analytics (like calculating averages etc) on blockchain data is usually done off-chain (ie. you obtain data from the blockchain via say a third party API call or directly from the blockchain and then do the data analytics off-chain someone else).

Is it possible and/or if it is possible, how do we do data analytics on-chain itself (which I assume would involve doing the data analytics on the smart contract itself)?

Would really appreciate any help or input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, it is possible but VERY inefficient unreliable and expensive due to multiple factors, including the price of native asset and  network congestion.

If you want to use solidity for basic forms of analytics you can actually do this by utilizing the [`eth_call`](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-call) RPC method. It is used for simulating txns and reading the state of the blockchain without actually having to make onchain payment for gas or contract deployment. You can build your analytics smart contract, instantiate it with your favorite ethereum library (like web3.js or ethers.js) and use `eth_call` to deployless-ly get data via your contract.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to perform data analytics on-chain, meaning directly on the blockchain itself. This approach involves executing data analytics operations within the smart contracts deployed on the blockchain network. However, there are several challenges and considerations to keep in mind when performing on-chain data analytics:

Gas Costs: Performing complex data analytics operations on-chain can be expensive due to the computational resources required. Every operation on the blockchain incurs a cost in the form of gas, which is paid in cryptocurrency.

Storage Limitations: Blockchains typically have limited storage capacity, so storing large datasets directly on the blockchain may not be practical. Instead, it's common to store only the necessary data or summaries on-chain, with the option to access more detailed data off-chain.

Security and Privacy: Blockchain data is immutable and visible to all participants, which may raise concerns about the privacy and security of sensitive data. Careful consideration must be given to data encryption and permissioned access mechanisms.

Scalability: Performing data analytics on-chain can be limited by the scalability of the underlying blockchain network. As more data is added to the blockchain, the performance of data analytics operations may degrade.

To perform data analytics on-chain, you would typically write smart contracts that define the analytics operations to be performed. These smart contracts would interact with the blockchain's data storage and processing capabilities to execute the analytics logic. However, it's important to carefully consider the trade-offs and limitations of on-chain data analytics before implementing them in a real-world application.

I hope this helps. I am learning Data Analytics at IIM Skills. Just felt like answering to the best of my knowledge. You can also read about the difference between [Data Analytics and Data Mining](https://iimskills.com/data-analytics-vs-data-mining/) here.

All the best!

Comment: Your answer looks like something an AI bot would have written.